# Best way to upload media from android?

Tags: android

So I have looked into multi part photo upload and http url connection so far on android. Http url connection seems faster than multipart. But a lot of the developers I know preffer multipart probably cuz showing a progress on it seems easier but does not work on some android devices. I have tried it on a chineese android with not much ram and the file didnt go through properly. What I'm wondering is that is there any other forms of file upload? Or a 3rd party lib?

Comment: There are plenty of libraries to help you upload files(Retrofit, Volley). I would advise you to encode the image to a Base64 String, and then upload it.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Retrofit 2](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) for doing this, It works perfectly on even slow old devices. I tested it on LG Optimus with android 2.something.

This is great tutorial to go through :

[Retrofit 2 — How to Upload Files to Server](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server)